# Unity rope/cable physics / anchor points

Tags: physics, unity, rope-physics

I'm creating a cable in Unity, which should behave realistically. I found 2 different ways to approach the problem.

First was to simply rigg a subdivided cylinder in Blender, Cinema4D or whatever editor you like and you set up hinge joints between the bones in Unity.

Second approach was to apply a Cloth Component in Unity. I tried the second approach with the cloth component. The physics work nice, but I don't know, how to make anchor points for the cloth object. I'm just able to add colliders, but the object is slipping away pretty fast from them.

So my first question is, which approach has the most benefits above the other and which benefits do they have. Second question, how can I create anchor points for my cloth object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use physics joints in bones of cable/rope model. You will get better physical result. Use configurable joint for more control.

We used same method to tank crawler and wheel.

Using cloth physics seems not related in your case.